# Raspberry Pi Temperature Logging & HTTP Requests

Tags: temperature

I've built a basic [web platform](http://desolate-spire-6651.herokuapp.com/) that will log data through HTTP GET requests anytime the following URL is hit: http://desolate-spire-6651.herokuapp.com/temperature_reading/save?temperature=70.5 My original goal was to do this with a Twine, but unfortunately it's currently broken.

In the meantime, I'd like to know how to send temperature data with a Raspberry Pi to my web platform through an HTTP GET request. Please note that I do not want to store or log the data on the Pi, I simply want the PI to send data to my web platform. Any suggestions?

Comment: While this isn't off-topic (as it is regarding the data being set from a Pi) this might get more attention and better answers on [so], which is a Programming-centered Stack Exchange. You can keep this question here, but I think it might be better on [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget` or `curl` will do what you want. e.g.

```
temperature="70.5"
wget http://desolate-spire-6651.herokuapp.com/temperature_reading/save?temperature=${temperature}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would also be pretty simple to do in Python, especially if you are already reading the temperature in a Python program.  The Python "requests" module is perfect for this; a short quick tutorial is available at:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/

Or thousands of other places, as a web search will show.